# how can i fetch recored week wise from between two dates in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am using this query for fetching the data day wise

```
SELECT 
     (count( server_time::timestamp::date)) , 
     server_time::timestamp::date 
FROM 
     complaint_details_v2 
WHERE 
     server_time between '2018/10/03' and '2018/10/11' 
GROUP BY 
     server_time::timestamp::date 
ORDER BY 
     server_time ASC
```

but I want to alter the above query week wise instead of day wise between two dates.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can group the dates into sevens by doing date arithmetic.

```
SELECT 
     (count( server_time::timestamp::date)) , 
     min(server_time::timestamp::date) as "week starting"
FROM 
     complaint_details_v2 
WHERE 
     server_time between '2018/10/03' and '2018/10/11' 
GROUP BY 
     floor((server_time::timestamp::date  - '2018/10/03'::date)/7)
ORDER BY 
     2 ASC
```

another alternative is grouping expression `date_trunc(week,server_time)` but that binds you to ISO weeks

Comment: its give me an error ERROR:  column "complaint_details_v2.server_time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 11:      server_time ASC